# Xml Сериализация несвязанных объектов C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialize

Добрый день! Как сохранить в один XML файл данные об объектах которые не знают про другие объекты?

У меня такие классы:
Тест - который не знает ни о чем, кроме своих данных.
Вопрос - который знает о тесте, к которому создан и о своих данных.
Ответ - который знает о вопросе, к которому создан и о своих данных.

Класс Test

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Test")]
public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Theory { get; set; }
    public bool IsShowTheory { get; set; }
    public string URLtoTheory { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get ; set; }
    public int CountRandomQoestions { get; set; }
    public int CountCorrectAnswers { get; set; }
    private Test()
    {

    }

    public Test(int id, string name, string theory, bool isShowTheory, string urlToTheory, DateTime date, int countRandomQuestion, int countCorrectAnswers)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Theory = theory;
        IsShowTheory = isShowTheory;
        URLtoTheory = urlToTheory;
        Date = date;
        CountCorrectAnswers = countCorrectAnswers;
        CountRandomQoestions = countRandomQuestion;
    }
}
```

Класс Question

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "QUestion")]
public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; }

    [XmlElement("Test", typeof(Test))]
    public Test Test { get; }

    public string Text { get; }

    private Question()
    {

    }

    public Question(int id, Test test, string text)
    {
        Id = id;
        Test = test;
        Text = text;
    }
}
```

Класс Answer

```
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Answer")]
public class Answer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Question", typeof(Question))]
    public Question Question { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool IsTrue { get; set; }

    private Answer()
    {

    }

    public Answer(int id, Question question, string text, bool isTrue)
    {
        Id = id;
        Question = question;
        Text = text;
        IsTrue = isTrue;
    }
}
```

Тест создаю примерно так:

```
        Test result = new Test(0, "C# basic", "Look in the WIKI", true, @"http:\\Wikipedia.ru", DateTime.Now, 2, 1);

        Question objectQuestion = new Question(0, result ,"What is the general type?");

        Answer objectAnswer1 = new Answer(0, objectQuestion, "string", false);
        Answer objectAnswer2 = new Answer(1, objectQuestion, "object", true);
        Answer objectAnswer3 = new Answer(2, objectQuestion, "int", false);
        Answer objectAnswer4 = new Answer(3, objectQuestion, "bool", false);
```

Как эти объекты сериализовать в подобный xml файл?

```xml
<Test>
    <Name>
    Основы C#.
    </Name>
    <Theory>
    Язык C# (c-sharp, си шарп) - современный объектно-ориентированный язык программирования. Он был разработан компанией Microsoft как один из языков для платформы .NET (.NET framework). Язык c# в наше время очень широко развит и продолжает развиваться: в нем появляются новые возможности, языковые конструкции, пополняется библиотека классов.
    </Theory>
    <IShowTheory>
    true
    </IShowTheory>
    <URLtoTheory>
    [url]https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp[/url]
    </URLtoTheory>
    <CountRandomQuestion>
    4
    </CountRandomQuestion>
    <CountCorrectAnswers>
    3
    </CountCorrectAnswers>
    <Question>
        <Text>
        Какой класс является базовым для всех классов в С#?
        </Text>
        <AnswerVariant>
            <Text>
            String
            </Text>
            <IsTrue>
            false
            </IsTrue>
        </AnswerVariant>
        <AnswerVariant>
            <Text>
            object
            </Text>
            <IsTrue>
            true
            </IsTrue>
        </AnswerVariant>
        <AnswerVariant>
            <Text>
            int
            </Text>
            <IsTrue>
            false
            </IsTrue>
        </AnswerVariant>
        <AnswerVariant>
            <Text>
            bool
            </Text>
            <IsTrue>
            false
            </IsTrue>
        </AnswerVariant>
    </Question>
</Test>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте в класс Test массив Question, и уберите из Question поле Test

```
[XmlElement ( ElementName = "Question" )]
public Question[ ] Questions;
```

У вас странная, на мой взгляд, логика. В коде не вопрос относится к тесту, а тест к вопросу, причем логика корректная в xml файле.

Comment: Согласен, массив с вопросами решит проблему, но Тест ничего не должен знать о вопросах. И не совсем понял где вы в коде нашли что тест относится к вопросу. 
Возможно вас запутали поля:
CountRandomQoestions - сколько слечайно выбранных вопросах нужно задать
CountCorrectAnswers - сколько нужно правильных ответов для прохождения теста.
В моем вопросе они никакой роли не играют.

Возможно ли создать подобный xml файл без жесткой привязки сущностей?

Comment: У класса Question есть поле Test. Тут и получается, что тест относится к вопросу. Как сделать без привязка я, к сожалению, не знаю. Возможно, вы более конкретно опишите задачу - и можно будет придумать другое решение. Но заметьте, что в xml файле у вас вопросы содержатся в тесте. А судя по коду, для того, чтобы найти вопросы теста, нужно пройтись по всем вопросам, и выбрать те, которые соответствуют текущему тесту. Если будет много тестов и вопросов, это будет очень долго.

Comment: @SlavaPodolskiy не стоит отмечать ответ правильным. Возможно, это действительно можно, просто я не знаю

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите сохранять именно **несвязанные** объекты, то можно поступить так. Создаём свой сериализатор для каждого типа объектов, открываем `XmlWriter` и вручную записываем корневой элемент. После чего можно туда писать любые объекты.

```
var xsTest = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test));
var xsQuestion = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Question));
var xsAnswer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Answer));

var settings = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true };
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create("test.xml", settings))
{
    writer.WriteStartElement("root");

    xsTest.Serialize(writer, result);

    xsQuestion.Serialize(writer, objectQuestion);

    xsAnswer.Serialize(writer, objectAnswer1);
    xsAnswer.Serialize(writer, objectAnswer2);
    xsAnswer.Serialize(writer, objectAnswer3);
    xsAnswer.Serialize(writer, objectAnswer4);
}
```

Читать из такого xml нужно с помощью опять же трёх сериализаторов нужных типов. Предварительно вручную пропустив корневой элемент (если вариант заинтересует, я напишу код).

Структура получившегося xml, конечно, не такая, как вам нужно. Но в вашем примере данные в файле как раз таки связаны. А для этого, как вам уже советовали, нужно добавить свойства-коллекции в ваши классы, содержащие другие объекты.